# IgniteSpiException while trying to connect to ignite cache from my local machine

Tags: ignite

I am having an application which is using the IgniteDb as a cache provider .It uses the discovery url as:
**127.0.0.1:47500..47509**.
Now i want to connect to this cache using java code in eclipse. I have written the code as:

```
 IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration().setBinaryConfiguration(
           new BinaryConfiguration().setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true)));
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder discoveryMulticastIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
       Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

       set.add("127.0.0.1:47500..47509");
       cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled (true);
       TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

       discoveryMulticastIpFinder.setAddresses(set);
       discoverySpi.setNetworkTimeout (5000);

    discoverySpi.setClientReconnectDisabled(true);

    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);

       discoverySpi.setIpFinder(discoveryMulticastIpFinder);

       cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi); 


     Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);

 IgniteCache<Integer, Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("person");    

        // Code to call cache put or get here
       // putCache(cache);
        //getCache(cache);
        System.out.println("All Available Cache on server : "+ignite.cacheNames());
```

But on running the erro i am getting the error as:

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers
 (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same)
 [locBuildVer=2.7.5, rmtBuildVer=2.8.0,



 locNodeAddrs=[aschauha-t470.apac.tibco.com/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, aschauha-t470.apac.tibco.com/10.98.51.252, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.0.101],


 rmtNodeAddrs=[aschauha-t470.apac.tibco.com/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, aschauha-t470.apac.tibco.com/10.98.51.252, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.0.101],
 locNodeId=e66eeea7-5427-4fe7-8368-884641af534b, rmtNodeId=35ad5deb-d212-4a85-812e-ec7d44caa4a8]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1997)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2099)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    ... 10 more
```

**Please help me in resolving the issue.
Also, the code which i mentioned above, is it the right way of connecting to the ignite db acting as cache for application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message tells everything needed:

**Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers
 (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same)
 [locBuildVer=2.7.5, rmtBuildVer=2.8.0,**

Ignite supports clusters from the same nodes only, so, you should either upgrade your local node to 2.8.0 or downgrade remote node to 2.7.5.

Comment: Hi thanks, can you please tell me how to do this.? Pleae bear with me as i am new to this technology.

Comment: Do you use maven for a local client node? If yes, then just upgrade version in maven for ignite dependencies